# Rails_admin javascript errors " has no method 'live' "

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-admin

I am experimenting with Rails Admin , while testing with has_many (polymorphic) association , I am not able to create new record in associated model.

[image]

I found some javascript errors, but I am not sure where that was the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Brad is right about the Jquery Error , I downgraded the Jquery-rails gem to lower version

gem "jquery-rails", "~>1.0.19"

But still its not only jquery error , I also forgot to add :pricings_attributes  is attr_accessible. After adding its works perfectly.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

the `live()` method was removed from jQuery. Use an older version (1.8 or below).

Comment: Hi Brad , thanks for quick answer. I know about this issue, but I am not sure how to do solve this in RAILS_ADMIN Gem.